# Trigger click event from dyamnically created ahref from Mail

Tags: c#, .net, windows, email, href

i am sending a mail from windows application. in that content i have a word "Acknowledge" as link.. If the user opens the mail in Outlook and click acknowledge i want to capture the date and time.and save it in my table. this is my requirement

i have done code in HTML in codebehind and getting the mail with acknowledge link but after that.. no idea to get the date & time in click event of "Acknowledge" link and update the same in table.

i am using C# .net 4.0

any ideas will be helpful ?

Below is the code i tried

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();                
                mail.To.Add(emailid);                
                mail.From = new MailAddress(emailid);                
                mail.Subject = "Invoice No : " + InvoiceNumberTextBox.Text + "";
                string Body = @"<p>Dear Team,</p><p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Please find the Invoice Details below :-</p><p><b><u>INVOICE DETAILS</u></b></p>
<table style=""height:60px;width:610px"">
<tr><td style=""width:250px;"">Invoice Number:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + InvoiceNumberTextBox.Text + @"</td></tr>
<tr><td style=""width:250px;"">Company Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + HRPartyNameTextBox.Text + @"</td></tr>
<tr><td style=""width:250px;"">Amount:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + HRAmountTextBox.Text + @"</td></tr>
<tr><td style=""width:250px;"">Joint Venture:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + JointVentureComboBox.Text + @"</td></tr>
<tr><td style=""width:250px;"">Request Raised On:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + chequeReqdate + @"</td></tr>
</table>
<br/><br/>

<a href="">Acknowledge</a>
<p>Regards</p>
<center>***** This is auto generated mail, please do not reply to this mail *****</center>";

                mail.Body = Body;                
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

                smtp.Host = "mailrelay.XXXX.com";
                smtp.Port = 25;
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("emailid", "");
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Send(mail);
            }

            catch (Exception sm)
            {
                sm.ToString();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to execute code on the client machine to get the date and time when `Acknowledged` is clicked (which is what I think you're asking).

The best solution would be to generate a URL with a GUID, or some type of unique identifier that you already have, and pass it to a page on your server to process it.

> Link click **>** web page receives URL with unique ID **>** update DB
>   accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You will  need to set the target for the link back to your own asp.net server and when the user then clicks on the link, it will be easy to record this in your database.